# iOS Fastest method to extract a substring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have several thousand strings in the form "verb-noun" for which I want to extract the noun portion. I am looking for the FASTEST way to do this. The verb and noun portions can be any length.

I have tried

```
NSString *noun = [[verb componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] lastObject];
```

Which is slow... For my list of over 3000 entries it takes about 3 seconds.

Also tried

```
NSString *noun = [verb substringFromIndex:[verb rangeOfString:@"-"].location + 1];
```

which is MUCH faster, about a half second.

Anyone have suggestions for making this even faster?

Comment: Change your source data...

Comment: Where do your strings come from?  In what format do you get them?  Do you **have** to use `NSString` at all, or can you use arrays of `char` or `unichar` directly?

Comment: Most likely fastest, for relatively short strings, would be to do a for loop over the string, using characterAtIndex to fetch one char at a time and compare to "-".  Then substringFromIndex after you find that position.

Comment: Could you split up the work into multiple threads? A little divide and conquer?

Comment: How are you looping over these 3000 entries? What does that code look like?

Comment: Hot Licks: CFStringInitInlineBuffer would be much faster than a characterAtIndex loop. Beware encoding- and locale-correctness issues though, and don't be so sure than a straightforward loop will beat a proper search algorithm, though naturally the shorter the string the less of a win more complex approaches will be.

Comment: @Catfish_Man - There are several things you can do to optimize the search if you have some knowledge of the statistics, and several ways you can gain faster per-character access at the expense of more setup.  The "-" character itself is pretty benign, locale-wise, and you'd only need to worry about oddities if dealing with some sort of encoding that UTF can't handle in single characters.

Comment: The strings are in an array built from an XML extraction (done once). The loop is a for each loop.

Comment: But if you do the (quite expensive) XML extraction only once, why do you not convert the data into a "friendlier" form at that time, so that performance is not an issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your work with these strings is thread-safe then one option is to use GCD to iterate over multiple `verb` values simultaneously, bringing multiple cores into action. Use `dispatch_apply` instead of whatever loop you're using, something like:

```
dispatch_apply([myWordArray count], queue, ^(size_t i) {
    NSString *verb = [myWordArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *noun = [verb substringFromIndex:[verb rangeOfString:@"-"].location + 1];

    // do something with noun...
});
```

Just keep in mind that this *will* do more than one pass simultaneously, so be very sure about threading issues.

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way would probably to sort the most likely cases for where the hyphen is, and then check for those first without using a loop. For example, if the most likely cases for index of hyphen are 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 2 in that order, you could do this:

```
NSString * verb = @"verb-noun";
NSString * noun = nil;

//use do...while(0) to avoid nested if else

do
{
    if([verb characterAtIndex:5] == '-')
    {
        noun = [verb substringFromIndex:6];
        break;
    }
    if([verb characterAtIndex:4] == '-')
    {
        noun = [verb substringFromIndex:5];
        break;
    }
    if([verb characterAtIndex:6] == '-')
    {
        noun = [verb substringFromIndex:7];
        break;
    }
    if([verb characterAtIndex:7] == '-')
    {
        noun = [verb substringFromIndex:8];
        break;
    }
    if([verb characterAtIndex:3] == '-')
    {
        noun = [verb substringFromIndex:4];
        break;
    }
    if([verb characterAtIndex:2] == '-')
    {
        noun = [verb substringFromIndex:4];
        break;
    }

} while(0);

//if not one of most likely cases, loop
if(!noun)
{
    for(int j = 8; j < verb.length; j++)
    {
        if([verb characterAtIndex:j] == '-')
        {
            noun = [verb substringFromIndex:j + 1];
            break;
        }
    }
}

if(noun)
{
    //noun should never be nil
    NSLog(@"found the noun");
}
```